# What do you call a transformer separated from a wall plug?

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer, adapter, 5v

I got a hold of (from a friend) a AC->DC 5v 2a power transformer - it connects to the wall with lamp cord/ figure-8 connector, and has a USB plug on the other side.

*I can't for the life of me find this (or anything like it) anywhere to purchase.*

I don't even know how to search for it.  I've searched by its Samsung model number, Amazon & Ebay for "power adapters", "travel adapters", etc. with no luck.  Everything has the 2 prong wall plug connected to the actual adapter (trying to avoid the wall wart).

Does anyone have suggestions, or know how to find these? Do I need to make one from scratch?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you can't find anything searching for its Samsung model number, smells like cheap Chinese item with the Samsung logo smacked on it for credibility. Have you actually verified its performance at 2A? I would guess it's questionable at best.

Comment: Looks like the Nexus10 charger.

Comment: @MattYoung: If it really is the N10 charger then it delivers a nice solid 2A, but the photos are too bad to be sure.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Things like this are so often counterfeited, I'm automatically skeptical when someone says "I got this from my eBay/myfriend/whateverotherunauthorizeddistributionchannel".

Comment: @MattYoung: True that, but given its rather unique format and usually having the samsung logo I would be inclined to say that this is much less copied than your standard 2A-really-200mA wallwart.

Comment: You specifically want an inline one, rather than a "wall wart"?

Comment: @MattYoung I once bought a box of 10 allegedly "CE marked" chargers for $10 just to see. Not only did they not bother to fake the certification the casing could come apart in your hand.

Comment: @pjc50 Have you seen the EEVBlog episode where Dave tears the fake bricks apart? Criminally bad...

Comment: @pjc50 yes exactly, I just want an inline one, like this, that is 5v 2a, that is relatively small & cheap.

Comment: zomg this is a shopping question!!!!!!!11111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try search a **desktop** adaptor/AC/DC power/USB output, etc..

Comment: thank you, that showed more results, especially from these two sources:
--
http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/SL-Power/MENB1010A0503F01/?qs=eE5%2FDRCJopbOdSEX%252bvdm4A%3D%3D&kpid=495957071
--
http://www.powerstream.com/ac-0520.htm

Comment: there are a few other power supply manufacturers you can check: like cincon, cui inc, Qualtek, megaelectronics.com, etc

Answer (score 0):

Those are modular supplies. The connector where the figure 8 plugs in can take a direct plug, that has us or euro or whatever mains connector. By coincidence they also use the IEC 60320-1 C7 and C8 Figure eight connector.

This is done because it is cheaper to make one universal 120/240 power supply, and a bunch of physical adapters, which can then be paired as needed. Smart/cheap manufacturing.

One particularly well known oem who uses these type of adapters is Apple, for both laptop, tablets, and I believe iPhone as well. So a oem iPad charger will work like this.

Comment: In the case of the N10 charger (which might be that on the crappy picture) there is an adapter included which "transforms" this thing into a wallwart.

Comment: Is there no way to purchase these without buying a marked up Apple product?  I'm trying to find something cheap/large quantity, and I don't want to manufacture these myself.

Comment: Is not a mark up, is the cost of a well engineered and safe and up to u.e. standards product. The cheap and knockoffs take considerably unwise shortcuts. That said, look for other manufacturers that use the same type of charger, or ebay clones. Or simply ask a manufacturer or reseller if they have a iec 60320 c7 connector version.